# Is there simple regex to convert Java String List to Oracle IN condition?

Tags: java, regex

For example:

There is a List of String (ArrayList < String >) `shopList`, and output toString() like this

```
[bread, sugar, butter]
```

now I need to convert this List to an Oracle IN condition, so that it become:

```
('bread', 'sugar', 'butter')
```

I use

```
String shopListString= "(".concat(shopList.toString().replaceAll("[\\s\\[\\]]", "'")).concat(")");
```

but first, I try to avoid concat but use regex alone, also it just output following which is wrong:

```
('bread,'sugar,'butter')
```

only last item comes with beginning `'`

Comment: It seems odd to me to approach this with RegEx. It should be simple with Java's string processing capabilities.

Comment: What is your java version?

Comment: @anubhava JDK7 but need to compatible to 6 :(

Comment: You have a list and you want to turn it into a string, parse that string and transform it into another string representing a list? Why don't you just create a string from the original list using the Java equivalent of `string.Join`? Alternatively, just use a `for` loop and construct it yourself. This a horribly frightening approach.

Comment: All the answers so far are vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: SQL Injection bug in 3, 2, 1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple way base on @Keppil:

```
"('"+ StringUtils.join(myList, "','") + "')"
```

This is origin answer use `group` variable to replace:

```
"("+ StringUtils.join(myList, ",").replaceAll("(\\w+)", "'$1'") + ")"
```

You can use `StringUtils` `join` string and surround `group` variable to replace the word.

Comment: Why not just do `"('"+ StringUtils.join(myList, "','") + "')"`?

Comment: Do I need to update my answer? or can you answer directly?

Comment: Feel free to update yours if you feel it is an improvement.

Comment: Thanks for the simple and quick solution

Answer (score 4):

Here's a Java 8 example:

```
// example list
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(){
    {add("bread");add("sugar");add("butter");}
};
// result
// initializing StringBuilder with starting "("
String oracle = myList
    .stream()
    // collecting as "," separated CharSequence, enclosed in "(" and ")"
   .collect(Collectors.joining("','", "('", "')"));

System.out.println(oracle);
```

**Output**

```
('bread','sugar','butter')
```

**Notes**

- The idea here is to use (hidden) iteration rather than parsing and transforming the `String` representation of the `List`.
- In Java idioms older than Java 8 that would require a little more code, and some "imperative"-styled ugliness (see valid answer from Casimir et Hippolyte).
- Thanks to [Keppil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1343161/keppil) for the much improved solution.
- As [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3430807/andreas) mentions, beware unsanitized values. You may want to build a format `String` with as many placeholders as your `List`'s elements, then use a `PreparedStatement` instead.

Comment: There is another joiner that does most of the work here: `myList.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("','", "('", "')"))`.

Comment: @Keppil nice, overlooked that one. Will amend shortly!

Comment: @Andreas a classic! and worth mentioning in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

loop over your arrayList elements and use a stringBuilder.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("('");
int lastIndex = myList.size() - 1;
for (int i=0; i < lastIndex; i++) {
    sb.append(myList.get(i));
    sb.append("','");
}
sb.append(myList.get(lastIndex));
sb.append("')");
```

Note: I assumed that the arrayList isn't empty.

Answer (score -1):

```
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("(");
    //assume this list is populated
    List<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i =0;i<str.size();i++) {
         String temp = "'" + str.get(i) + "'";
         sb.append(temp);
         if(i != (str.size() -1)) {
             sb.append(",");
         }
    }
    sb.append(")");
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```