# Weird behaviour with collection and StringBuilder

Tags: java, collections, stringbuilder

I try to make a SQL query with objects contained in a `Collection` and a `StringBuilder`. It seems to be a very simple code to write:

```
public String makeQuery(Collection<MyObject> collection) {

    logger.info("The size of the collection is {}", collection.size());

    StringBuilder queryString = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO my_table (my_column) VALUES ");
    int i = 1;
    for (MyObject object : collection) {

        queryString.append("('");
        queryString.append(object.get...);
        queryString.append("')");

        if (i == collection.size()) {
            queryString.append(";");
        } else {
            queryString.append(",");
        }
        i++;

    }

    logger.info("The size of the collection is {}", collection.size());

    return queryString.toString();

}
```

For me, this code should works but sometimes I have this result:

```
 INSERT INTO my_table (my_column) VALUES ('a'),('b');('c'),
```

How is that possible that the semi colon is not the last character ?

**EDIT**

I added logs before and after the loop, and the size of the collection is always the same.

Comment: Use a `PreparedStatement`. Also take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35205617/is-there-simple-regex-to-convert-java-string-list-to-oracle-in-condition/).

Comment: is collection shared to other threads?

Comment: @AdamSkywalker only if there is a bug in my program. I will take a look at that.

Comment: cannot infer the incorrect behavior by just reading this code, unfortunately

Comment: Could you print _i_ and _collection.size()_ at each iteration ?

Comment: this is bug-prone code and you should get rid of it. It poses a sql injection risk, and could cause problems if the order of columns in the schema isn't what you expect.

Comment: I'm aware of the risk of the SQL injection but it's not the problem I want to solve for now.

Comment: *"but sometimes I have this result"* ... sometimes? Are you sure that the posted code is responsible for this? Since there are whitespaces between each value, but your code doesn't write whitespaces there.

Comment: @Tom no it's not exactly the same code. I changed the table name and the number of columns but I don't think it's relevant.

Comment: I'm not talking about the table name or the columns, I'm talking about this `('a'), ('b'); ('c'),`, because your code can only produce this `('a'),('b');('c'),`. So are you sure that you're looking at the right place and there isn't similar code somewhere else, which actually produces your output and has the problem? Have you used a debugger?

Comment: @Tom I removed the whitespaces because you're right, they're not supposed to be there.

Comment: Ok, so this _is_ the code snippet which causes the problem. Well I guess there is only one possible source for this error remaining: like  AdamSkywalker suggested, you're probably sharing this collection between threads and get a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) here. The posted code snippet itself is ok.

Answer (score 1):

You could try just use Iterator() and untill it hasNext() just do the normal appending. When hasNext() returns false just append ';'. Don't need the extra if's then.

Comment: Or if you want to stick with the current loop, just add commas all the way down, then after the loop [delete](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#deleteCharAt(int)) the trailing comma and replace with a semicolon

Comment: For me using an Iterator or a for each loop is pretty much same thing. Somewhere I need a test to check if it's the last element. Maybe you can enlighten me how you would do it.

Comment: hasNext returns false when it's the last element. So in a while(iter.hasNext()) and append ';' after while-loop. Inside while you just take iter.next() to append to your StringBuilder.